# Развертывание проекта в Azure из CI Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins

Имеется сервер с Jenkins, на котором происходит сборка проекта. Как из Jenkins развернуть собранный проект на виртуальной машине в Azure?

Comment: Не плохая статья на сайте [microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-azure-slave-plugin-for-jenkins/). Расписано все подробно.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал [эту статью ](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/articles/storage-java-jenkins-continuous-integration-solution/) и [Эту](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/)
Также есть [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mcuvlkqVT0) и готовый [туториал](https://msopentech.com/blog/2015/04/16/tutorial-using-ant-and-jenkins-to-automate-the-deployment-of-java-projects-from-the-azure-toolkit-for-eclipse/#) Материала очень много

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй комментарий к вопросу навёл меня на решение.

Подготовительные шаги:

**Шаг 1.** Открыть порт 5985 или 5986 (для зашифрованного соединения) в настройках Azure и брандмауэра виртуальной машины;

**Шаг 2.** Выполнить winrm quickconfig в cmd.exe или Enable-PSRemoting в PowerShell для виртуальной машины;

**Шаг 3.** Установить на обе машины Azure Sdk для Powershell;

**Шаг 4.** Установить плагин Windows PowerShell для Jenkins.

Шаги, выполняемые Jenkins:

**Шаг 1.** Собрать проект;

**Шаг 2.** В Jenkins выполнить как команду Windows

```
winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="адрес_виртуальной_машины"}
```

Следующие два шага выполняются как PowerShell-скрипты.

**Шаг 3.** Файлы, готовые к развёртыванию, загружаются в Azure Storage с сервера с помощью `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`;

**Шаг 4.** Удалённо выгрузить файлы на виртуальную машину из Azure Storage с помощью команды `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent`. Эта команда должна быть заключена в блок скриптов для команды `Invoke-Command`, которая удалённо выполнит этот блок на виртуальной машине.

*Примечание*: Если нужно зашифрованное соединение с виртуальной машиной через порт 5986, то необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

**Шаг 1.** В PowerShell создать сертификат, если он отсутствует и скопировать Thumbprint нового сертификата

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName <наименование_сертификата> -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

**Шаг 2.** В командной строке выполнить следующее

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname=”<наименование_сертификата>”; CertificateThumbprint=”<thumbprint_сертификата>”}
```